# How to get Kivy id

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I just started to learn kivy and I try to create 2 screens app

Now I have AttributeError:

box = self.ids.box
File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 864, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.**getattr**
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '**getattr**'

my .kv file

```
WindowManager:
    FirstWindow:
    SecondWindow:


<FirstWindow>:
    name: "first"

    MDRoundFlatButton:
            text: "LOG IN"
            font_size: 12
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "second"
                
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"


<SecondWindow>:
    name: "second"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height
        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            GridLayout:
                cols: 2

                Label:
                    text: "Watchlist Screen"
                    font_size: 32

                BoxLayout:
                    id: box
                    size_hint_y: .8
                    pos_hint: {"top":1}
```

How should I call id Box

```
lass AwesomeApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):

        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file('login.kv')

class FirstWindow(Screen):
    pass

class SecondWindow(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        y = [5, 12, 6, 9, 15]

        plt.plot(x, y)
        plt.ylabel("This is MY Y Axis")
        plt.xlabel("X Axis")
        
        
        box = self.ids.box
        box.add_widget(FigureCanvasKivyAgg(plt.gcf()))


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    AwesomeApp().run()
```

Is there any good books about Kivy?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the id by

```
self.ids.<your_id>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).